# bootstrap 4 - equal height columns - align button bottom

Tags: bootstrap-4

OK, known problem - bootstrap equal height columns. I have a row with 3 cols, within the cols there is a div with "h-100" to make the cols equal height an a "border", so the lines are inside the cols an there is a optical gap between the cols. Then there is the content (image, headline, text) and a button. This button should always be placed at the bottom of the column.

I found a solution with position absolute, but i think this is not the optimal solution.
I try to solve this with the flexbox, but but find no working way. Maybe someone knows how to do this in a proper way with "align-end".

THX for any idea.

Demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mimii/9dpqv3mj/41/)

```css
p.btn-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid p-5">
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
      <div class="border h-100 pb-5">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        <h2>Normal Text col-1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
        <p class="my-3 btn-bottom"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
      <div class="border h-100 pb-5">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        <h2> Less Text col-2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p class="my-3 btn-bottom"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
      <div class="border h-100 pb-5">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        <h2>More text col-3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
        <p class="my-3 btn-bottom"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>      
  </div>
</div>
<<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check below code. I used flex column class to align items vertically & then add mt-auto class in button area which fill blank space and stick button to bottom.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid p-5">
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
      <div class="border h-100 d-flex flex-column">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        <h2>Normal Text col-1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
        <p class="my-3 btn-bottom mt-auto"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
      <div class="border h-100 d-flex flex-column">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        <h2> Less Text col-2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p class="my-3 btn-bottom mt-auto"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
      <div class="border h-100 d-flex flex-column">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        <h2>More text col-3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
        <p class="my-3 btn-bottom mt-auto"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>      
  </div>
</div>
<<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex – apply `flex` and `flex-column` to your border div and use margin (`mt-auto`) to push your button to the bottom. Setting the images to `align-self-center` will keep them their normal size.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid p-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <div class="border h-100 d-flex flex-column">
                <img class="align-self-center" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
                <h2>Normal Text col-1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
                <p class="my-3 mt-auto"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Button</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <div class="border h-100 d-flex flex-column">
                <img class="align-self-center" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
                <h2> Less Text col-2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                <p class="my-3 mt-auto"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Button</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <div class="border h-100 d-flex flex-column">
                <img class="align-self-center" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
                <h2>More text col-3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
                <p class="my-3 mt-auto"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Button</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

THX for the help :-)
Works fine.

I tested several things with d-flex and flex-column, but i used align-end within the button. "mt-auto" within the button is the solution !!!

Answer (score 0):

I have write down the answer hope it will helps you(Iam using bootstrap 5)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="html_to_dom.js"></script>
    <style>
       .parent{
        width:1000px;
        display:flex;
        margin:auto;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
       }
       .child {
       
    flex-basis: 300px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    margin: 10px;
   
}
 .card-content{
flex-grow:1;
padding:10px;
}
.btn-card{
    margin:10px;
}
.child h4{
    background-color: #3a3737;
    padding: 7px 3px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child child-1">
        <h4 class="card-heading">Management</h4>
        <div class="card-content">
            <p class="card-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            
        </div>
        <button class=" btn btn-primary btn-card">Click Here</button>
    </div>
    <div class="child child-2">
        <h4 class="card-heading">Finance</h4>
        <div class="card-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo consequatur enim eos magnam quam? Iure omnis aperiam mollitia a iste minima, fugiat sit quibusdam vitae quam ipsa beatae eveniet, voluptatibus nisi voluptas et delectus dignissimos voluptatem ducimus porro odit corporis quaerat distinctio? Non quis quasi quaerat cupiditate reiciendis, pariatur ipsum odit? Deleniti, architecto temporibus! Ab cumque eos quis doloribus iusto.</p>
       </div>
       <button class=" btn btn-primary btn-card">Click Here</button>
    </div>
    <div class="child child-3">
        <h4 class="card-heading">Science</h4>
        <div class="card-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, ipsa architecto. Repellendus optio non corporis quos? Consequuntur, soluta qui ad quasi impedit tenetur voluptate eligendi dolorem a optio cum laudantium, repudiandae doloribus, minus repellat error dolor? Ratione aut, laudantium ea minima necessitatibus autem reprehenderit cumque ut inventore. Quae, reiciendis qui. Est expedita dolor quibusdam ut nulla aperiam, excepturi in ratione culpa, debitis eos saepe facilis beatae nostrum! Iure, obcaecati similique. Consectetur illo quia suscipit sunt?</p>  
        </div>
      <button class=" btn btn-primary btn-card">Click Here</button>
    </div>
    <div class="child child-4">
        <h4 class="card-heading">Agriculture</h4>
        <div class="card-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, ipsa architecto. Repellendus optio non corporis quos? Consequuntur, soluta qui ad quasi impedit tenetur voluptate eligendi dolorem a optio cum laudantium, repudiandae doloribus, minus repellat error dolor? Ratione aut, laudantium ea minima necessitatibus autem reprehenderit cumque ut inventore. Quae, reiciendis qui. Est expedita dolor quibusdam ut nulla aperiam, excepturi in ratione culpa, debitis eos saepe facilis beatae nostrum! Iure, obcaecati similique. Consectetur illo quia suscipit sunt?</p> 
        </div>
       <button class=" btn btn-primary btn-card">Click Here</button>
    </div>
    <div class="child child-5">
        <h4 class="card-heading">Pharmacy</h4>
        <div class="card-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, ipsa architecto. Repellendus optio non corporis quos? Consequuntur, soluta qui ad quasi impedit tenetur voluptate eligendi dolorem a optio cum laudantium, repudiandae doloribus, minus repellat error dolor? Ratione aut, laudantium ea minima necessitatibus autem reprehenderit cumque ut inventore. Quae, reiciendis qui. Est expedita dolor quibusdam ut nulla aperiam, excepturi in ratione culpa, debitis eos saepe facilis beatae nostrum! Iure, obcaecati similique. Consectetur illo quia suscipit sunt?</p>
        </div>
        <button class=" btn btn-primary btn-card">Click Here</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```